HTML drag and drop feature is slow and only registers the second click and drag
I have read a few of the other questions that describe the same issue however none clearly provide an answer or explanation of the issue.
I have created a kanban, centered around a calendar in html, the calendar in question is the python calendar module where i create a custom calendar in order to input events. the functionality of the board is working well, however the click and drag functionality works, but only on the second click and drag.
page HTML:
<div class="board">
<div>
    {{c| safe}}
</div>
<br>
<div class="dustbin">
    <img class="dustbin-icon" src="{{url_for('static', filename='icons/icons8-dustbin-96.png')}}"
        alt="Dustbin Icon">
</div>

page JS:
<script>
function updateKanBan(task, elem) {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/update_task", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "frame": elem,
            "task": task,
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    });
};
function deleteTask(task) {
    fetch("http://127.0.0.1:5000/auth/deletetask", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "task": task,
        }),
        headers: {
            "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
        }
    });
};
function createKanBan() {
    const draggables = document.querySelectorAll(".task");
    const droppables = document.querySelectorAll(".lanes");
    const deletable = document.querySelector(".dustbin");


    draggables.forEach((task) => {
        task.addEventListener("dragstart", () => {
            task.classList.add("is-dragging");
        });
        task.addEventListener("dragend", () => {
            task.classList.remove("is-dragging");
        });
    });

    droppables.forEach((zone) => {
        zone.addEventListener("dragover", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const bottomTask = insertAboveTask(zone, e.clientY);
            const curTask = document.querySelector(".is-dragging");
            if (!bottomTask) {
                zone.appendChild(curTask);
            } else {
                zone.insertBefore(curTask, bottomTask);
            }
        });
        zone.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            const curTask = document.querySelector(".is-dragging").innerText;
            const frame_task = zone.closest('.days').querySelector("label").innerText;
            updateKanBan(curTask, frame_task);
        })
    });

    const insertAboveTask = (zone, mouseY) => {
        const els = zone.querySelectorAll(".task:not(.is-dragging)");
        let closestLane = null;
        let closestOffset = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;
        els.forEach((task) => {
            const { top } = task.getBoundingClientRect();
            const offset = mouseY - top
            if (offset < 0 && offset > closestOffset) {
                closestOffset = offset;
                closestLane = task;
            }
        });
        return closestLane;
    };
    deletable.addEventListener("drop", (e) => {
        const curTask = document.querySelector(".is-dragging");
        const actualTask = curTask.querySelector("p.task-desc").innerText;
        if (curTask) {
            deleteTask(actualTask);
            curTask.remove();
        }
    });
};
createKanBan();

Calendar Code:
import calendar
class CustomHTMLCalendar(calendar.HTMLCalendar):
    def __init__(self, tasks, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # Store tasks in a dictionary where key is the day of the month
        self.tasks_by_day = {
            day: [] for day in range(1, 32)
        }  # Initialize dictionary with empty lists for each day
        for task in tasks:
            self.tasks_by_day[int(task.frame)].append(task)
def formatday(self, day, weekday):
    """
    Return a day as a table cell.
    """
    if day == 0:
        # day outside month
        return '<td class="%s"><label>&nbsp;</label></td>' % self.cssclass_noday
    else:
        tasks_html = "".join(
            f'<div class="task">{task.desc}</div>'
            for task in self.tasks_by_day.get(day, [])
        )
        return (
            f'<td class="%s"><label>%d</label><br><div class="lanes">{tasks_html}</div></td>'
            % (
                self.cssclasses[weekday],
                day,
            )
        )

My thinking is it is slow because of the amount of event listeners created, as one per calendar day i required for the drag and drop functionality but i also assumed it was the
{ c | safe }

Python Route code:
@auth.route("/plan-board")
def plan_list():

tasks = db.session.query(Task).all()

c = CustomHTMLCalendar(tasks, calendar.MONDAY)
c.cssclasses = ["days", "days", "days", "days", "days", "days", "days"]
c.cssclass_noday = "days"
c = c.formatmonth(2024, 4) 

return render_template("maintenance/Maintenance/plan-board.html", c=c)

In summary:
I need to click and drag a task twice in order to move it from one calendar day to another and i havent found a reason for the delayed action.
Any help, id greatly appreciate.
